# Getting hold of a dormant gem namespace

Tags: ruby, namespaces, rubygems

I have written a ruby gem that I would like to make available to the community.  Unfortunately, the name I want to use is already taken by another gem.

This is the namespace I would like:
https://rubygems.org/gems/magi

And the gem that uses that name links to here: https://github.com/r7kamura/altria  - which is clearly a different gem name.

How would I go about requesting and gaining control of the namespace for that gem - who do I need to get in contact with, and what steps do I take?  I haven't published gems to rubygems before, and the documentation seems a little sparse.

Comment: Namespace in context of Ruby usually means modules, but you may be using it in other sense. If so, it is not clear what you are writing about. "The gem that currently owns the namespace actually has a different name" sounds gibberish to me.

Comment: If you bothered to follow the link, you would see that "Magi" was a temporary name, and it is now this gem  "https://github.com/r7kamura/altria"

Comment: I don't bother to follow your link. Questions posted here are supposed to be conclusive within this page.

Comment: edited to make more clear.  Would be nicer for you to offer help rather than downvote.

Comment: Gems require unique names. Nothing enforces unique module namespaces except programmer vigilance.